# OCaml function comparing numbers

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function that takes 3 numbers, x y z. If x is equal to y, then it should return z. Otherwise, return x. I am having trouble figuring out why my attempt always returns z, even if x!=y. Any help would be appreciated I am still new to OCaml.

```
    let test x y z =
      match x with
      | y when x = y -> z
      | _ -> x
```

Comment: Your `y` on line 3 is shadowing the function argument. It's simple the value of `x` rebound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesn't compare `x` to `y`, it uses the pattern `y` to match against `x`. This always succeeds and binds `y` to the value of `x`. That is, you're creating a new local variable `y` that has the same value as `x`.

To fix your code, you could do this:

```
let test x y z =
  match x with
  | _ when x = y -> z
  | _ -> x
```

But that seems a bit silly when you could just do:

```
let test x y z =
  if x = y then z else x
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but we could realize that because of the way OCaml functions work, we can write:

```
% rlwrap ocaml
OCaml version 5.0.0~rc1
Enter #help;; for help.

# let test x y =
    if x = y then Fun.id
    else Fun.const x;;
val test : 'a -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

All OCaml functions take one argument. The syntax makes this a bit more palatable by letting us specify multiple arguments more easily, but that's still how it fundamentally works.

As such, `test 4 5` simply returns a function which takes a further argument and produces an `int`. We can use the [`Fun`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Fun.html) module to determine _which_function it should return. This module is newer than the question, so I guess this is a message from the future.

`Fun.id` is a function which returns whatever value's passed into it. This is appropriate for the case where `x = y`. If not, we return `Fun.const` which takes two arguments and always returns the first. If we partially apply `x` to this, we get a function which will always return the value of `x`.